# American wording of "to drop litter"

Tags: american-english, transatlantic-differences

When I google "drop litter", only results from British websites appear.

What is the typical way in America to warn against littering?

Is it simply "do not litter" or is the verb "drop" also used?

Comment: "No littering" seems to be what I've always seen in the US. "Don't (Do not) litter", too. Can you edit the question title to be in line with the body?

Comment: As an American, I saw "drop litter" in this question and thought some military medics had dropped a patient.  The process of creating litter has pretty much always been called *littering* in my experience. "Don't litter" is exactly right for AmE.

Comment: It's trash when it's in your hand or in the proper receptacle, it becomes litter through the act of littering.

Comment: Uh… 'litter' as a noun is something that might be dropped. 'Litter' as a verb is an action that involves dropping litter. Which do you want?

Comment: In the south when a dog gives birth to multiples we say she drop litter of puppies

Comment: In the US, "litter" is a verb meaning to release waste materials onto a surface where they are not wanted.

Comment: As a non-speaker of BrE, I don't see how 'drop litter' fits into a larger sentence. Can someone from there give a sentence where this is used (and maybe parts of speech)? As is I can't make sense of it (or I can force a sense on it like others in comments have but it sounds bad).

Comment: @Mitch BrEn has the verb "to litter" but it isn't normally used for the action of dropping waste carelessly. It's used mainly in the past tense to describe a space, for instance "his desk was littered with papers", "the floor was littered with the stuffing from the pillows". We treat 'litter' in the carelessness case as a noun so we need a verb (usually 'drop') to describe the action. It's pretty much the same as describing the action of dropping _specific_ litter, for example 'He dropped a cigarette packet". The cigarette packet becomes litter when it's dropped.

Comment: @BoldBen All those meanings you mention for BrE hold in AmE (but I suppose you're pointing out that BrE does not say things like 'He is littering (when he drops his trash in the street)'. Either way, what I really want to have in the OP is a -BrE- phrase where the exact sequence 'drop litter' occurs and to know what a BrE speaker means by it, so that I can try to figure out what the corresponding Americanism might be, which is what I think the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Mitch We use the phrase "dropping litter" in the way that you use "littering" to mean releasing litter into the environment. A US notice would say "No littering" but a UK one would say "Don't drop litter".  It's the only case, so far as I know, where we wouldn't use "litter" as a verb. I suppose the difference is that we don't use "to litter" intransitively, we would talk generally about "people littering the streets with fast food containers" but we would refer to the actions of an individual allowing his Big Mac carton to fall to the ground as "dropping litter" not "littering".

Comment: @BoldBen Ah OK "Don't drop litter" parses perfectly well for me (in AmE), though yes I'd much more likely see 'Don't litter". Now everything makes sense. Would it be a bad thing for me to alter the OP to have it talk about "Don't drop litter" rather than, what sounds to me like dropping a drawer full of cutlery down the stairs, what I can at most call the pair "drop litter"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Laurel's great answer, here is a list of the situation for 'litter' in AmE and BrE:

In AmE, 'litter' can be used in both noun and verb forms when talking about trash that is freely on the ground and not in a trash receptacle.

As a noun:

> "Put the litter in the trash can."

As a verb:

> "You're littering if you throw your cigarette out the car window."

and the ubiquitous

> "Don't litter."

It seems in BrE that using 'litter' as a verb is not done: the last two items are not used. Instead in BrE you'd normally say

> "You're dropping litter..."

or

> "Don't drop litter"

The latter, with 'drop', makes sense in AmE, but it is just not used at all because you would say "Don't litter".

Comment: As I said in one of my comments on the original post the only way we don't use "litter" as a verb is intransitively but in US English the intransitive form is completely accepted. Even transitively we would more commonly use 'to litter' with an indirect object as well saying things like "Littering the streets with fast food containers".

Answer (score 10):

No, Americans don't use "drop litter". Instead, you'll find signs that just say "no littering", such as this one:

> [image: no littering, circle with slash over guy littering]

There are also signs that say "do not litter":

> [image: please do not litter, guy puts trash in can]
>
> Images from [Recycle Reminders](http://www.recyclereminders.com/do-not-litter-signs)